# a python print statement not shown when run through pipeline and tee command

Tags: python, tee

I'm using simple function w1(str) to sometimes make the program stop and wait for a key. The code below works.

file : test.py

```
#!/bin/env python

def w1(str):
    print (str)
    wait = raw_input()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('started..')
    w1('press a key')
    print('exiting..')
```

How it runs (ok) :

```
ckim@stph45:~/test] test.py
started..
press a key

exiting..
```

But when I run `test.py | tee log`, it doesn't show anything and if I press a key it finishes not printing the message and waiting for the key. Actually, teh problem is the `print(str)` is not displayed on the screen when run through tee command and it was waiting for my key. How can I make this `print(str)` shown even when I run it with `|tee` ?

EDIT : ok I learned that `python -u` does the trick. But originally my python script has `#!/bin/env python` at the beginning of the script so I run it `test.py | tee log`. I searched the net and found I can do :

```
ckim@stph45:~/test] setenv PYTHONUNBUFFERD 1
ckim@stph45:~/test] $test.py | tee log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-u` to unbuffer,

```
python -u test.py | tee log
```